# Migrate a SQL Server DB using .BAK file in Oracle SQL Developer What's the encoding scheme

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to Migrate a SQL Server Database to Oracle 11 and am using the Migration Wizard in Oracle SQL Developer.

On step four using offline mode I've identified the location of the .BAK file generated using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, in the area below where you identify the source file (the backup database file location), there is a drop down list with over fifty different file encoding schemes to select from.

Which one is it that I should choose because when I hit next and get to the Capture screen the dialog that is supposed to be populated with the database within the previously identified .bak file is empty.

Comment: Specifically what is the encoding scheme that I should chose from the dropdown list in step four of the wizard?

Comment: A quick google search says that you can't restore from a MSSQL .bak file to an Oracle database. https://community.oracle.com/thread/2367301

Comment: I think you have to use an ETL tool for that, Talend or Pentaho are free and easy to use.